# Visualizing Multiple Networks in R using Igraph

Tags: r, networking, visualization, igraph

I need to visualize a very large number (10k) of distinct networks, all on the same page, and label each node a type (binary). Each network aside from a few are relatively small. Link lengths/weighting is not important for this dataset, and a high degree of overlap on the bigger networks is fine as long as density is evident.

I have gone over some of the Igraph documentation and have been able to create individual graphs using a node/link list. However, I would like some insight if possible on how to translate this large number of networks (currently just 10k arrays with node identity and type inside) into 10k plots, and whether this is a feasible task with Igraph.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A fairly standard page of single spaced text has 80 letters per row times 60 rows, just under 5000 characters.  So in order to fit 10K graphs on a page,  you would need to make each graph be half the size of a single letter. That does not seem useful.

Comment: Wouldn't `par(mfrow=c(*number of rows*,*number of columns*))` work? At 10,000, the page will need to be very long if the networks are to be readable, but I think that base command will get you there. Otherwise, look into something like `trelliscope` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trelliscope/index.html